# facebook test users with extended permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Apps making use of 'extended permissions' features of the facebook graph API require reviewing by facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review .

Facebook lets you make 'test users' so that the reviewers can try out your application.

However, when I try to use the graph explorer to query the API with my app and a test user -  I cannot make use of anything which requires extended permissions - it also doesn't work from within my app. How can I use extended permissions with test users?

Answer (score 0):

Test users still need to go through the same login flow in order for the test users to grant the app permissions.

The exemption for developers and test users is primarily related to whether these permissions can be granted using the login dialog.

Comment: I created some test users and did not select the 'auto authorise this app' option so that it forced me to accept the permissions when I logged in as the test user. However, for certain endpoints the API still responds with "you must be a developer of this application". Since it's not possible to make the 'test users' also 'testers' of the application - I am quite stuck.

Comment: If your test users are not allowed to access certain features, whereas your developer account is allowed, would you mind filing this as a bug on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs?

Comment: Found a related, older bug and commented there https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/404510959620416/

Comment: That bug does not seem related. Your issue seems related to test users not having access to features during development which requires approval. Please open a new bug and detail the api's/arguments that produces this issue.

Comment: bug is filed here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/702677679786289/ 
Would appreciate any feedback on the bug report, i.e. whether it is sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature, not a bug, of the Facebook API. At least in the case of read_mailbox permissions.

Even if the test user explicitly grants this permission, the API will reject any calls because they are not developers of the application. So the answer is that you **can not** use test users in this case.